# conditional subsetting from data.frame in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset

I have a `data.frame` **[HERE](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/k.csv)**. I was wondering how I can subset variables named as `dot.names` (*see below*) for rows in the data.frame for which variable `control` is `FALSE` AND *alphabetically order the answer* based on `D$study.name` in **BASE R**?

Here is the code I used without success:

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/k.csv") # data.frame

dot.names <- c("ESL", "prof" ,"scope", "type")             

D[dot.names & !control]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `D$control` is a logical column -

```
res1 <- D[order(D$study.name), ]

res2 <- res1[!res1$control, dot.names]
```

If `D$control` is character column -

```
D[D$control == "FALSE", dot.names]
```

A on-liner using `subset` -

```
subset(D[order(D$study.name), ], !control, select = dot.names)
```

With `dplyr` -

```
D %>% 
  filter(!control) %>% 
  arrange(study.name) %>% 
  select(dot.names)
```

Comment: @rnorouzian They should be. Try- `dot.names <- c("mpg", "hp");
res1 <- mtcars[order(mtcars$wt), ];

res2 <- res1[res1$cyl == 4, dot.names];

res3 <- subset(mtcars[order(mtcars$wt), ], cyl == 4, select = dot.names);

identical(res2, res3);

all.equal(res2, res3)`.Also try `all.equal()`. Identical is very strict I think. Let me know.

Comment: I think your solutions are not identical `nrow` for your `subset` solution gives `33` rows, BUT `nrow` for your `res2` solution gives `40` rows !!!